# Problems building Twitter's Fabric API in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to install Fabric and have followed the instructions (add Run Script Build Phase, Build, Drag files into project (copy off)) and all looks good.

However as soon as I try to run the app, I get a flood of errors:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/michael/Developer/Digicub/Mini2/MGBF2/APIs/ParseChat/Framework'
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TwitterKit(TFSScribe.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPersistentStoreCoordinator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TwitterKit(TFSScribe.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TFSScribeEvent in TwitterKit(TFSScribeEvent.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TFSScribeImpression in TwitterKit(TFSScribeImpression.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectModel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TwitterKit(TFSScribe.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TwitterKit(TFSScribe.o)
  "_NSSQLitePragmasOption", referenced from:
      -[TFSScribe _setupManagedObjectContext] in TwitterKit(TFSScribe.o)
  "_NSInMemoryStoreType", referenced from:
      -[TFSScribe _setupManagedObjectContext] in TwitterKit(TFSScribe.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TwitterKit(TFSScribe.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TFSScribeEvent in TwitterKit(TFSScribeEvent.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TFSScribeImpression in TwitterKit(TFSScribeImpression.o)
  "_NSSQLiteStoreType", referenced from:
      -[TFSScribe _setupManagedObjectContext] in TwitterKit(TFSScribe.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've retried a few times, uninstalling, reinstalling. Thought it might be clashing with Twitter.framework, but removing this doesn't have any effect. Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: Try adding the CoreData framework to your project.

Comment: That did the trick - thanks! I didn't see that in their list of required frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments by @rmaddy
Add CoreData framework worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your bundle should look like this:

[image]